# Section of code with up to N threads executing in FIFO order

Tags: c#, multithreading, algorithm, parallel-processing, synchronization

I have a section of code which should be executed by a maximum number of threads lower than N and also the order in which threads are calling someFunction() should be reflected in the order in which they are entering the section, that is FIFO order.

If I use the [Semaphore](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.semaphore.aspx) I have no control over the order in which threads are entering the section.

> "There is no guaranteed order, such as FIFO or LIFO, in which blocked
>   threads enter the semaphore."

The initial attempt:

```
class someClass
{
    static volatile Semaphore semaphore;
    ...

    someClass()
    {
        semaphore = new Semaphore(N,N)
    }

    someType someFunction(InputType input)
    {
        try
        {
            semaphore.WaitOne();
            /* Section Begins */
             var response = someHeavyJob(input); // submitted to the server
            return response;
            /* Section Ends */
        }
        finally
        {
            semaphore.Release();
        } 
    }
}
```

If I combine a Semaphore and a ConcurrentQueue as follows thread may come back with a response to the request brought by other thread what would require significant changes  in other parts of code.
What is the .NET 4.5 solution for the following problem:

1. Allow for maximum number of threads lower than N in the section of code
2. The order in which threads are entering the section is FIFO
3. Threads will get the response for the request they brought (and not the response to the request brought by other threads)

   ```
   class someClass
   {
       static volatile ConcurrentQueue<someType> cqueue;
       static volatile Semaphore semaphore;
       ...

       someClass()
       {
          cqueue = new ConcurrentQueue<someType>();
          semaphore = new Semaphore(N,N)
       }

       someType someFunction(Request request)
       {
           try
           {
               cqueue.enqueue(request);
               semaphore.WaitOne();
               Request newrequest;
               cqueue.TryDequeue(out newrequest);

               /* Section Begins */

               var response = someHeavyJob(Request newrequest); // submitted to the server
               return response;
               /* Section Ends */
           }
           finally
           {
               semaphore.Release();
           }
       }
   }
   ```

UPDATE:
I am clarifying my question:
SomeHeavyJobs() funciton is a blocking call to the server on which this job is being processed.

UPDATE2:
Thank you all for answers. For the record: I ended up using the [FIFO Semaphore](http://dcutilities.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Semaphore/FifoSemaphore%20&%20Mutex/FifoMutex%20Tutorial%20and%20Implementation%20Discussion)

Comment: could you be more specific ? bit hard to understand your some class and some type... and what are you want to fix in your code

Comment: What I want to do is to limit the number of threads executing a section of code to N where N > 1 and still maintain FIFO order

Comment: If you are talking about several threads executing at the same time, it's a bit hard to talk about "order". Can you elaborate on that a bit? Also, your queue and semaphore should be `readonly`, not `volatile`.

Comment: @Groo: I didn't make it clear in the question but I am talking about limitning the number of threads in a section of code. Also the order I am taking about refers the the order in which threads get to the barrier, that is a semaphore in this case.

Comment: @matcheek: how about using the `Tasks` namespace? It does a pretty good job at scheduling. Alternatively, you can create your own thread pool.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'If I combine a Semaphore and a ConcurrentQueue as follows thread may come back with a response to the request brought by other thread what would require significant changes in other parts of code.'

I hate to say it, but I would suggest 'changes in other parts of code', even though I don't know how much 'significance' this would have.

Typicaly, such a requirement is met as you suggested, by queueing messages that contain a reference to the originating class instance so that responses can be 'returned' to the object that requested them.  If the originators are all descended from some 'messagehandler' class, that makes it easier on the thread that will call the function, (which should be a member of messagehandler).  Once the thread/s have performed the function, they can call a 'onCompletion' method of the messagehandler. 'onCompletion' could either signal an event that the originator is waiting on, (synchronous), or queue something to a private P-C queue of the originator, (asynchronous).

So, a BlockingCollection, one consumer thread and judicious use of C++/C# inheritance/polymorphism should do the job.

Strangely, this is almost exactly what I am being forced into with my current embedded ARM project. The command-line interface thread used for config/debug/log is now so large that it needs  a massive 600 words of stack, even in 'Thumb, Optimize of size' mode. It can no longer be permitted to call the SD filesystem directly and must now queue itself to the thread that runs the SD card, (which has the largest stack in the system to run FAT32), and wait on a semaphore for the SD thread to call its methods and signal the semaphore when done.

This is the classic way of ensuring that the calls are made sequentially and will cetainly work.   It's basicaly a threadpool with only one thread.

Like the other posters have written, any other approach is likely to be, err.. 'brave'.

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at [Smart Thread Pool](http://smartthreadpool.codeplex.com/)?

**[Edit]**

If I am still getting the problem right, as I've stated in the comments, I don't believe that a multithreaded solution is feasible for this problem.

If a task *k* cannot be started before task *k-1* has finished, then you only need a single thread to execute them. If you are allowed to execute *some* combinations of tasks in parallel, then you need to specify the rules exactly.

Comment: I believed that this kind of challenge is so common that a native .NET solution might exist.

Comment: @matcheek: I find the challenge *uncommon*, actually. You cannot ensure that a thread isn't rescheduled before it even hits the lock. This means that you specifically need to check whether your previous task has started executing (this may be as simple as setting a volatile int counter), before continuing with the next task. But even then, threads can easily get descheduled and their execution order mixed up.

Comment: It looks like my cutting-all-the-unnecessary-details approach to make the  question clearer is hitting me back. What I did not mention in the quetsion is that someHeavyJob is actually I/O what causes thread to wait for a response from the server which processes jobs in order.

Comment: @matcheek: if `someHeavyJob` executes on server, and each job must be finished before the second one start, then it seems like you only need a single background thread to fire requests sequentially.

Answer (score 1):

> also the order in which threads are calling someFunction() should be
>   reflected in the order in which they are entering the section, that is
>   FIFO order

This is not possible by principle.

```
semaphore.WaitOne(); //#1
var response = someHeavyJob(input); //#2
```

Even is Semaphore was strictly FIFO, the following could happen:

1. All threads enter the section in FIFO order (1)
2. All threads get descheduled from the CPU (between 1 and 2)
3. All threads get rescheduled in random order or even in LIFO order (between 1 and 2)
4. All thread start entering someHeavyJob in arbitrary order (2)

You can never ensure that the threads will "enter" the function in a specific order.

As for a FIFO semaphore, you can build a Semaphore yourself using a lock and a Queue. Looks like your already did that and posted the code. This approach is correct as far as I can tell.

Comment: I think he's expecting to build a system in which if the threads get descheduled and then rescheduled in random order they will still wait their turn to enter the method i.e. a thread at position k in the queue gets rescheduled but will be put back to sleep until the threads k-1...1 make progress.

Comment: @Tudor, I also think he wants that. But it's impossible. The thread can even switch order *inside* the method. He can control ordering regarding access to the section though.

Comment: For a critical section a good  approximation of the solution could be a Bakery Algorithm http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lamport's_bakery_algorithm.
I have not found anything similar for a section of code with up to  N threads allowed.